# Statistical tension between two measurements

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics

If we have two measurements of the same quantity, say, $m_1=a\pm c$ and $m_2=b\pm d$, how many sigma away are these values? In other words, when we say that two measurements are in e.g. $3$ sigma tension, which measurement sigma ($c$,$d$, or combination thereof) do we refer to?

Comment: In what context are you asking. What do you know about the uncertainty distributions characterised by c and d ?

Comment: For simplicity, say for example that m1 is a Gaussian with μ1=a and σ2=c and m2 is also a Gaussian with μ2=b and σ2=d. A good example are the Hubble constant measurements, one from Planck and one by Riess et al., which are currently in 4.4σ tension. If we know the a,b,c,d of these measurements, where does this 4.4σ come from?